# Match strings with an if clause without checking capitals in php

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$a = 'abc';
$b = 'AbC';

if ($a == $b)
{
    echo 'abc == ABc!';
}
else
{
    echo 'abc != ABc!';
}
```

Now it echoes `abc != ABc!` but i'd like it to match the strings regardless of the capitals.

Comment: Convert both strings to upper case or lowercase and then compare them. [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Comment: Just a friendly nitpick. Next time you post code please ensure the test snippet you post actually executes. You are missing several `;` in that example

Comment: woops, sorry. Changed the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1) convert the casing and do a comparison.

```
strtolower($a) === strtolower($b)
```

One caveat of this is that for non-utf8 characters and non-english languages this does not work well.

2) use case insensitive comparison

```
if (strcasecmp($a, $b) == 0) {
```

[strcasecmp docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

Comment: Thanks! `strcasecmp` works perfectly! I checked out `strtolower` earlier but it wouldn't convert Ä to ä, which i kinda needed.

Comment: I did note that its not good for non-utf8 but forgot about non-english languages. Thanks for the feedback - I have amended my answer with that information in case someone comes across it in the future.